Establishing a connection between local code and Google Colab
I want to program a reinforcement learning code, specifically MADDPG. The code will also use Gazebo ROS. So each step there will be Neural Network training, then using the output model to take an action and get reward.
Is it possible to use Google Colab, specifically Google's NPU, ONLY for Neural Network training, and use local machine to run the rest of the code (taking action and getting reward)? If needed, going Colab Pro is fine, I just a bit confused on how to integrate the code.
Is there a way for local code to connect to Google Colab?
Maybe like server client connection, with google Colab NPU as server and local code as client?
